# Child div's top border located at start of parent div

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with the footer portion of my website.

**Basic Layout:**

`footer_bg` is the parent div. It contains 3 divs in horizontal side-by-side formation: `address_Sec` (left most), `blog_Sec` (in the middle) and `follow_Sec` (right most). Before these 3 divs, but also within `footer_bg`, is a forth div named `footerMessages`.

**Problem:**

The problem is that the browser thinks that `footerMessages` div starts at the point where `footer_bg` div is starting. However in reality, `footerMessages` div appears below the other 3 divs, also within `footer_bg`. This confusion causes the `border-top` property for `footerMessages` to render where the parent div, namely `footer_bg`, is starting.

**JSFiddle Code:** http://jsfiddle.net/ahmadka/Th6Kq/1/

**Screenshot example:**

[image]

The red dashed line should appear right before where the copyright messages start, because the copyright messages are in `footerMessages` div..

How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/Th6Kq/2/

You should add: `clear:both` to footer messages.

Comment: Why does it cause the scrollbars to appear ?

Comment: Scrolbars will not appear on your page, jsfiddle have 'space problem' -> element height is in question i guess -> resize frame, and you will see... http://fiddle.jshell.net/Th6Kq/2/show/

Comment: P.S. Change widths and position of elements in footer (put them in rows, on bellow other) if you want responsive view...

Comment: You mean put them vertically one by one ?